# Wiring up Spring Boot with Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm trying to do simple metric/observability in my Spring Boot application using Micrometer, Prometheus and visualizing that metric on Grafana. I have created minimal example on [GitHub](https://github.com/Coding-Hefestus/springboot-prometheus-grafana). Essentially, I will have a scheduled job, which will be making HTTP request to some other service. I need to do 20k of those requests during single hour. I want to let it run, and measure what was the mean/average rate of request duration during that single hour.

As I understood from reading the docs, Grafana is natively capable to issue PromQL queries to Prometheus, which scrapes data from Actuator. Not sure exactly what Micrometer's role is, but from my understanding it acts as a facade in case we use deferent type telemetry systems, other the Prometheus.

So there are two problems:

**Problem 1**

I added following bean and annotated method which makes HTTP to external service. Will be using Feign (as I see, Micrometer also "tracks" Feign, need to look further for that config):

```
@Bean
public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
    return new TimedAspect(registry);
}
```

and my service method:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService {

@Timed("email.time")
public EmailMessageResponseDto sendEmail(EmailMessageRequestDto emailMessageRequestDto){
        //TODO: This is the place where Feign Client will be used to send email
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I make a request to my endpoint (`http://localhost:8089/sendEmails`) which invokes `sendEmail` method, I don't see `email_time` on Prometheus's metric at `http://localhost:8089/management/prometheus`.

What I don't also understand is how I can visualize `email_time` on Grafana?

**Problem 2**

I cannot see anything on Grafana's dashboard. I can tell that datasource in Grafana is correctly set. Grafana is on `http://localhost:3000/` (credentials: **admin** **admin**). I see different dashboards are available but there's no any metrics. So the file is in `docker/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/spring-boot-statistics.json` is being picked up. I found it on Grafana marketplace.

[image: Grafana image]

If is of any significance, Boot version is 2.4.4 and Java is 1.8. Our project is currently on those versions.

Comment: You can first go to the prometheus endpoint of your application and call it by yourself, as long a you cannot see the metric there, it will never the visible in grafana. Check this first. e.g. `http://localhost:8089/management/prometheus`. Do you have the `micrometer-registry-prometheus` dependency?

Comment: I checked/prometheus, its not there :( Dependency is in pom.xml No idea why its not in Prometheus

Comment: I mean Prometheus server is up and running I can see the UI and container is running, but queries are not showing anything..

Comment: You need to check the actuator endpoint of your application which is scraped by prometheus for the metric.

Comment: That endpoint is this one: `http://localhost:8089/management/prometheus`, there are other metrics for jvm etc, but not `email_time`

Comment: Maybe your code is then never called; you can inject the MeterRegistry Bean and call some method on the registry to see if any tag comes through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample project might have everything you want: https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/teahouse

It contains 3 Spring Boot apps that talk to each other, they use Prometheus, it has Grafana dashboards and a load generator to generate traffic, you can see it in action here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQHuFnKvk_U

## Problem 1

In newer versions of Boot (3.1+) you don't need to add a `TimedAspect` `@Bean` but you need `spring-boot-starter-aop`. Also, I would recommend using `@Observed` instead.

## Problem 2

I think Prometheus is not scraping your service, if you open the Prometheus UI go to the "targets" menu and see if your app is there and OK. You need to change the Prometheus config to add your app, you can check the Prometheus docs or the Teahouse example above.

Comment: Hi Jonatan, thank you for the reply. You were right, Prometheus was not working correctly. Instead of `127.0.0.0:8089`, I had to set `host.docker.internal:8089`. Thanks for the link, will look it up!